# Displaying all images from a WordPress post (including media library)

Tags: wordpress, image, post, wordpress-theming

With this function, I'm getting only those images that I uploaded using the upload button in the post section.
But, if I add an image from the media library it's now showing. I want to show all the images from the post.

How can I show all my images from the post?

```
$attachments = get_children(array('post_parent' => $post->ID,
              'post_status' => 'inherit',
              'post_type' => 'attachment',
              'post_mime_type' => 'image',
              'order' => 'ASC',
              'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'));

              foreach($attachments as $att_id => $attachment) {
                $full_img_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
                echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'full');
               
              }
```

[image: Here is the image of upload and media library]

Comment: `post_parent` is the issue, when you upload an image in the media library then `post_parent` is empty. when you upload an image from any page or post,  `post_parent` is set as the current page/post ID.

Comment: Is there any option to solve it? @VijayHardaha